# angular2 with asp.net core and systemjs installation

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

i tried to start a project  Angular2 / TypeScript / ASP.Net Core
with  NPM / Gulp / SystemJS

But it seems that all the tutorial out there are not uptodate or i'm missing something...

When i try -> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
Visual studio is not building anymore and saying that it cannot find the module '@angular/core'.

Here are my configs files:

NPM:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/router": "3.1.2",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.1.2",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "moment": "^2.14.1",
        "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.24",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
        "systemjs": "^0.19.37",
        "typings": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "3.9.1",
        "gulp-clean": "0.3.2",
        "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.9.1",
        "gulp-typescript": "3.1.3",
        "gulp-uglify": "2.0.0",
        "typescript": "2.0.10"
    },
    "name": "kira",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "typings install dt~core-js --global"
    },
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'wwwroot/app',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

My app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})

export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work after many hours! I needed to ask a question to find the solution few minutes after...

My problem were in my tsconfig.json

I was using 'module': 'system' that was not working (i don't really know why...)

I changed this to 'module': 'commonjs' and now everything is building !! :D

EDIT:

I found the reason why "system" was not working as module for my tsconfig.json.
Because i'm using Node.js for my module packaging and node use commonjs to unpack those module, so we need to put commonjs in tsconfig so typescript can read them.